# Is it possible to deploy Tekton on Google Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-run, tekton

I know Tekton can be deployed on Kubernetes. As Google Cloud Run is Knative running on Kubernetes, is it possible to deploy Tekton to Cloud Run? The use case behind the question is to have the Tekton components only fire up when a webohook is fired from source control

Comment: Cloud Run (Managed) is Knative on Borg. Please post a problem with code and error messages, logs, etc. As written your problem is too broad and does not identify a clear specific problem. Problem statements like "Is it possible ..." are generally off-topic. Post a real problem after you have attempted to solve the problem. Please read these guides: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @JohnHanley, the question is specific not broad. To phrase it differently, is there a component in Tekton that requires a persistent runtime, or can it run solely in a serverless environment? If you have an answer, please provide one. If your issue is with the question itself being posted on this site, then please suggest a more appropriate alternative

Comment: @JohnHanley, while I understand you're frustrated at not being able to provide the answer, please refrain from spamming the comments by posting again the same links that didn't answer the question. And let's keep the values of Stack Overflow in mind when we communicate on this platform: Learn, share, grow, keep community at our center. Thanks